# VirtualBox cannot create virtualization of Windows 8.1 under Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: virtualbox, osx-snow-leopard, windows-8.1

Windows 8 is telling me that I don't have a 64-bit processor, but I do (my Macbook is a 2010 model, all of which come with 64-bit processor).

"This 64-bit application couldn't load because your PC doesn't have a 64-bit processor.
...
Error code 0xc000035a"

Also, I have enabled PAE/NX in VirtualBox. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What version of virtual box do you have?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you select `Windows 8.1 (64bit)` instead of `Windows 8.1` in the Version settings of the VM. I made this mistake as well and it threw that error.